# Did Sheev Palpatine have the power to cloud the minds of the Jedi when he was a young boy?

Tags: star-wars, star-wars-legends, jedi, darth-sidious

I am wondering if Sheev Palpatine had always had the ability to mask his Force abilities and cloud the minds of the Jedi, even as far back when he was just a young boy.

Did Sheev Palpatine have the power to cloud the minds of the Jedi when he was a young boy?

Comment: If only Baby Sheev’s parents managed to change his diaper 5 minutes earlier before he was seduced by the Dark Side, the GFFA would be a different place.

Comment: is there a canon version of events re: his early childhood? This question, in it's premise of 'an alternate version of events' presumes there is a known version. The first paragraph lends itself to opinion based answers, and the second paragraph is a worthwhile question, but not sure if there is any canon material to use to answer it. Perhaps tag the question w/ "legends" and one could use the Darth Plageius book

Comment: @NKCampbell, I will edit the question and how the Body text is written to try to reduce the number of opinion based answers.

Comment: i think just adding that legends tag was enough, at least for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are aware from the ST that strong dark side practitioners can impact lives even in the womb, so there is no telling how early Sheev got his dark start. But it may depend on when young Sheev started down the dark path which would forever dominate his destiny.

If young Sheev, already in mom’s womb was on the path of the dark side, then the dark side may be able to cloud the Jedi even then. Or while learning to walk as a toddler, if instead of grabbing the corner of the Palpatine family’s coffee table or stairs, Baby Sheev embraced the dark side, then the dark side may be able to cloud the Jedi even then.

So, because the dark side is able to forever dominate destinies of those who start down its path, the key to your question is when Sheev started that path, which could conceivably be as early as before being born.